# Using jQuery to set multiple selects using each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page full of selects, and they all have a common class.  I need to set every one of them to their first option.  Easy, right?  But what I finally wound up getting to work feels like such a hack... is there a better way?

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {
    var firstOptSelector = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' option:first'; // HACK
    $(firstOptSelector).attr('selected','selected');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {
   this.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZDYjP/

Answer (score 2):

How about this short one?

```
​$(".myclass :first-child").prop("selected", true);​​​​​​​​​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/u8S54/

Comment: @thecodeparadox well internally it has to iterate over the list of elements.. either internal or external it is the same.. :P

Comment: @Vega Yep, it is just shorter. Yours should be a bit faster though :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {
    $(this).find('option:first').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use each. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/zUyb2/).

```
​$('.select').find('option:first').prop('selected', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option:first", ".myselect").prop('selected', true);
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/69wxq/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the selected property then the first one by default is what is shown.

```
$('.myclass').find('option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
```